# Conditionally set value in previous row, within group

Tags: r

I have a data frame "df" like this, grouped by "nest."

```
  nest  laid  stage
    1    NA     2
    1     5     4
    1   -10     NA
    2    NA     1
    2     3     1
    2    -8     NA
```

I want to make a condition so that if "laid" is > 0, the "stage" of that nest at the previous visit is set to 0. If "laid" is not greater than 0, I want no change in "stage".

Desired outcome:

```
  nest  laid  stage
    1    NA     0
    1     5     4
    1   -10     NA
    2    NA     0
    2     3     1
    2    -8     NA
```

I've tried different versions of code below (dplyr and tidyr), with various errors:

```
df1 <- df %>%
  group_by(nest) %>%
  mutate(stage, if(laid > 0){stage = 0}) %>%
  fill(stage, .direction = "up")
```

I've gone over similar questions, but they all use ifelse. Any tips are much appreciated!

Comment: My required change is not limited to the first row of group, I want the same conditional change for the 2nd, 3rd, etc. stage of a particular nest

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `if_else` (or `ifelse` if you are not certain of the column data types), which is a vectorized version of `if/else`; To check the next `laid` value, use `lead`:

```
df %>% 
    group_by(nest) %>% 
    mutate(stage = if_else(lead(laid) > 0, 0L, stage))

# A tibble: 6 x 3
# Groups:   nest [2]
#   nest  laid stage
#  <int> <int> <int>
#1     1    NA     0
#2     1     5     4
#3     1   -10    NA
#4     2    NA     0
#5     2     3     1
#6     2    -8    NA
```

Comment: Beautiful, thank you!! Tip for others - I had errors with Psidom's code, but changing from numeric to integer fixed it

Comment: @Emily please consider accepting this answer (check mark) if it helped you. It lets the community know that the answer worked for your problem.